# Why are BibTeX and friends separate programs?

Tags: bibtex, biber

Let us compare two tasks that would appear quite similar, at least to my untrained eye: Managing a table of contents and creating a bibliography. In both cases, it involves creating separate files with extra data in them and running LaTeX multiple times. The difference is, in the case of the bibliography, I need a separate program like BibTeX or Biber (well, LaTeX *can* create its own bibliography, but it is quite simple and --- in my opinion --- ugly and inflexible).

What I do not understand is *why* we need a separate program for this; to my ears, scanning a document for references and storing these references in a file sounds like what TeX is best at. **Why are BibTeX and friends separate programs?**

Comment: the big difference between a bibliography and a table of contents is sorting, it's possible but painful to sort in tex, and certainly would have severely strained the available tex memory at the time bibtex and makeindex were written

Comment: There is a self-contained solution to what you're looking for: http://ctan.org/pkg/librarian

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is the memory capacity in TeX really that limited? Even though it now runs on 21st century desktops?

Comment: @Gaussler you asked why they are separate programs, bibtex dates from 1985 and yes tex memory was _very_ restricted at that time. Even by 1994 when latex2e was introduced, you basically had no room for any macros on top of the latex format, which is why latex2e is the size it is.

Comment: The fact that `biblatex` -- a thoroughly modern LaTeX package -- needs either bibtex or biber to perform sorting (among other tasks...) should be a clear indication that sorting isn't a task TeX (the macro programming language) is well equipped to handle. Well, maybe one day there will be a Lua-based implementation of the required sorting steps, in a package that requires the Lua(La)TeX format. Until that happens, it's much more efficient to invoke an external program (bibtex or biber) to perform the sorting-related tasks.

Comment: Why did one of the greatest computer scientists of all time create such a weak and poor programming language in the first place?

Comment: So he could typeset beautiful math papers

Comment: @Gaussler Knuth doesn't use LaTeX, he uses plain and does all of that sort of stuff by hand

Comment: "You can converge a toaster and a refrigerator, but those aren't going to be pleasing to the user," as Apple's Tim Cook said in 2012. Rather than try to create one humongous program that does everything under the sun, it's often much more efficient to create several smaller ones.

Comment: Well, I think many people will agree that much of the TeX life would have been a lot easier if the programming language had not been so limited. In other words, things would have been easier of Knuth had made other choices.

Comment: "Why did one of the greatest computer scientists of all time create such a weak and poor programming language in the first place?" He didn't. TeX is not designed as a general purpose programming language. It is like asking why Turing created something which produced such ugly typographic output. Knuth created TeX to typeset beautiful documents - not as a drop-in replacement for whatever the equivalent of python was at the time. There's also this: the approach fits the 'unix philosophy'. While that may be over generalised, there are several grains of truth to it.

Comment: Actually, I think things are probably easier in this case precisely because bibtex and friends are separate. It means that future development of biber, for example, does not need to choose between breaking with TeX altogether and utilising current methods and resources. Development of LaTeX, for example, has to work with core TeX. Development of biber doesn't have to start from bibtex. Also, this makes it possible to use biber without TeX. This can be extremely useful for manipulating bibliographic databases.

Comment: @Gaussler: A few years ago, at the TUG meeting to commemorate the 32nd anniversary of the release of TeX, Knuth was asked by a person in the audience about some design mistake he'd supposedly made. He replied candidly and frankly, "I firmly believe that every man is entitled to make a mistake in his life." [Aside: I suppose he would allow women to make one mistake in lifetime as well...] Some people's supposed mistakes are far more interesting and useful than other people's correct solutions. A healthy dose of humility never hurts, either.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are the abilities to sort going to be significantly improved with LaTeX3? There is at least a package called `l3sort`, but its documentation is practically non-existent.

Comment: @Gaussler well it's written in tex so it'll still be several orders of magnitutde slower than sorting in C. It depends. If machines are 1000 times faster and documents are only 100 times bigger then perhaps it is OK. But why does it matter? If the command you type is `foolatex` and internally it is a makefile that runs latex twice, biber, makeindex, and something else, isn't that just an implementation detail? (similar to context where is rarely run by directly executing TeX.)

Comment: Note that recently ConTeXt has gotten a new bibliography implementation, which I suppose works without external programs; see http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/081205.html.

Comment: Just to point out too that there are things you need to do for bibliographies like custom label generation which are quite hard and which need real arrays and so forth. It's not just sorting any more. The code in biber to do certain types of auto-disambiguation for labels, names and name lists is really quite tricky. I cannot imagine even attempting this in TeX.